# Python - Convert dictionary (having "list" as values) into csv file

Tags: python-2.7, csv, dictionary, export-to-csv

Trying to write below dictionary into csv file with desired output as mentioned below.

```
dict_data = {"1":["xyz"],
             "2":["abc","def"],
             "3":["zzz"]
            }
```

desired output:

```
1,3,2
xyz,zzz,abc
        def
```

Below code doesn't work as expected as it keeps both "abc" & "def" in same cell as shown below.

```
with open('k.csv','wb') as out_file:
writer = csv.writer(out_file,dialect = 'excel')
headers =  [k for k in dict_data]
items = [dict_data[k] for k in dict_data]
writer.writerow(headers)
writer.writerow(items)
```

output:

```
1,3,2
xyz,zzz,abc,def
```

Comment: In your "desired output", is the third line supposed to be ",,def", to put "def" in the third column (i.e., the one labelled "2")?

Comment: @K.A.Buhr : Yes. "def" should be placed in the third column right underneath "abc".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete solution:

```
    import csv
    import os

    class CsvfileWriter:

        '''
        Takes dictionary as input and writes items into a CSV file.

        For ex:-

        Input dictionary:

        dict_data = {"1":["xyz"],"2":["abc","def"],"3":["zzz"]}

        Output: (CSV file)

        1,3,2
        xyz,zzz,abc
        ,,def

        '''

        def __init__(self,dictInput,maxLength=0):

            '''
            Creates a instance with following variables.
            dictInput & maxLength

            dictInput -> dictionary having values(list) of same length

            ex:-
                dict_data = {"1":["xyz",""],"2":["abc","def"],"3":["zzz",""]}

            maxLength -> length of the list

            '''
            self.dictInput = dictInput
            self.maxLength = maxLength

        @classmethod
        def list_padding(cls,dictInput):

            '''
            converts input dictionary having list (as values) of varying lenghts into constant length.
            Also returns class variables dictInput & maxLength

            Note:
            dictInput represents the dictionary after padding is applied.
            maxLength represents the length of the list(values in dictionary) having maximum number of items.

            Ex:-

            input dictionary:

            dict_data = {"1":["xyz"],"2":["abc","def"],"3":["zzz"]}

            output dictionary:

            dict_data = {"1":["xyz",""],"2":["abc","def"],"3":["zzz",""]}


            '''
            cls.dictInput = dictInput
            listValues =  dictInput.values()
            listValues.sort(key = lambda i: len(i))
            maxLength =  len(listValues[-1])

            for i in listValues:
                while(len(i) < maxLength):
                    i.append('')

            return cls(dictInput,maxLength)

        def write_to_csv(self):

            with open('sample_file.csv','wb') as out_file:
                writer = csv.writer(out_file,dialect = 'excel')
                headers =  [k for k in self.dictInput]
                items = [self.dictInput[k] for k in self.dictInput]
                writer.writerow(headers)
                c = 0
                while (c < self.maxLength):
                    writer.writerow([i[c] for i in items])
                    c += 1

    dict_data = {"1":["xyz"],"2":["abc","def"],"3":["zzz"]}

    cf = CsvfileWriter.list_padding(dict_data)

    cf.write_to_csv()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works in Python 2:

```
import csv

dict_data = {
    "1":["xyz"],
    "2":["abc","def"],
    "3":["zzz"]
}

def transpose(cols):
    return map(lambda *row: list(row), *cols)

with open('k.csv','w') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file,dialect = 'excel')
    headers = dict_data.keys()
    items = transpose(dict_data.values())
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(items)
```

I can't take credit for the `transpose` function, which I picked up from [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/410687/?_ga=1.69170129.1714239084.1480233907).  It turns a list of columns into a list of rows, automatically padding columns that are too short with `None`.  Fortunately, the csv writer outputs blanks for `None` values, which is exactly what's needed.

(In Python 3, `map` behaves differently (no padding), so it would require some changes.)

Edit: A replacement `transpose` function that works for both Python 2 and 3 is:

```
def transpose(cols):
    def mypop(l):
        try:
            return l.pop(0)
        except IndexError:
            return ''
    while any(cols):
        yield [mypop(l) for l in cols]
```

Comment: Thanks for your insights @K. A. Buhr. This is very tempting approach but i'm bit worried on  version  incompatibility of map function. I would rather write my own function to append "None".